# Can't understand the ruby code

Tags: ruby

I can't understand what the below ruby code does. Can anyone give me some explanation. Thanks!

```
      map '/healthz' do
        run Healthz.new(logger)
      end
```

The Healthz is:

```
  class Healthz
    def initialize(logger)
      @logger = logger
    end

    def call(env)
      @logger.debug "healthz access"
      healthz = Component.updated_healthz
      [200, { 'Content-Type' => 'application/json', 'Content-Length' => healthz.length.to_s }, healthz]
    rescue => e
      @logger.error "healthz error #{e.inspect} #{e.backtrace.join("\n")}"
      raise e
    end
  end
```

And the lib used are:

```
require "eventmachine"
require 'thin'
require "yajl"
require "nats/client"
require "base64"
require 'set'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using eventmachine and thin, I'd guess that code is some kind of routing code for a simple web application.

That is, it maps the `/healtz` route of the application to the `Healtz` class, so that if you start up the app, and point your browser to `localhost:<whatever_port_thin_uses>/healtz`, it would start up a `Healtz.new` instance for you.

Since I don't know what `Healtz` actually does, I've no idea what will actually happen, but my guess is that it's some kind of rack application.

And, as I already stated, this is just my guess, from seeing the list of libs you're using.

Comment: Many thanks! Now I've pasted the Healtz class. You can have a check if you'd like.

Comment: Ok... It looks as if my guess was correct. It will initialize and call a `Healthz` object. The `Healthz#call` method should return a json document, containing whatever `Component.updated_healthz` returns. Basically, what you're looking at is a simple web application.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. As a fresh guy, there's long way to go